# getAccess Token failed: "The Spotify app is not installed on the device" but Spotify is on my device

Tags: ios, flutter, spotify

[image]

I am using the [spotify_sdk](https://pub.dev/packages/spotify_sdk) package for Flutter. When I deploy this code onto my iPhone SE, it will load the app, then open Spotify. When I look at the terminal, it prints the error code above in the terminal. After it opens Spotify, it goes to the redirect URL, but when I come back to the app, I cannot use any of the Spotify API features. Here is the code that calls to get the access token and connect to spotify. I have no clue if the application has connected to Spotify successfully or not.

```
  var accessToken = "";
  SpotifySdk.getAccessToken(
          clientId: "546624bfa7964f959b54e9da5e3dca0f",
          redirectUrl: "https://critica.app/",
          scope: "app-remote-control")
      .then((value) {
    print("ACCESS TOKEN: $accessToken");
    SpotifySdk.connectToSpotifyRemote(
            clientId: "546624bfa7964f959b54e9da5e3dca0f",
            redirectUrl: "https://critica.app/",
            accessToken: accessToken)
        .then((connected) {
      print(connected ? "Spotify is connected" : "Spotify is not connected");
    });
  });
```

On the Spotify API dashboard, I added myself (my Spotify account) as a user and the application is in Development mode. I pretty sure I followed all the steps until [Set Up User Authorization](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/ios/quick-start/) for iOS. None of these changed the error code in the terminal. I tried calling the function in different places throughout the app, but it just does the same thing every time. I don't really know how to debug this when it just says PlatformException every time even though I have the app.

Comment: Have you added the necessary url to your `LSApplicationQuerysSchemes` in `info.plist`?

Comment: @Paulw11 I just added it to info.plist, but it is not recognised when I open it in Xcode. I have to manually enter ```<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
 <array>
  <string>spotify</string>
 </array>```